# Filter on Client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have three checkboxes and a gridview(*using template*).
I am using my checkboxes for filtering the status of the rows(account) of the gridview. I can filter the gridview in server side, now what i want to happen is to filter the gridview via Client side wherein when the user checks one of the checkboxes it will show the the accounts with either Pending, Approved or Rejected without refreshing the page. How can i do this in jquery or javascript.

I have no codes yet, cause i don't how to begin.

this is my checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Pending" runat="server" Text="Pending" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="PendingConsumer_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="Approved" runat="server" Text="Approved" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="ApprovedConsumer_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="Rejected" runat="server" Text="Rejected" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RejectedConsumer_CheckedChanged" />
```

this is my gridview (i bidned it in my code behind):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvconsumer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="50%" OnRowDataBound="gvconsumer_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Consumer">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblconsumer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateCreated">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbldatecreated" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateCreated") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

this is my filter:

```
        int MerchantFilterID = int.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString());
    string sqlfilter = "id >= 1";
    DataView dv = new DataView(ClassBiller.FilterPendingConsumer(MerchantFilterID));

    if (Pending.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += " AND (Status = 'Pending')";
    }

    if (Approved.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += (sqlfilter.Contains("AND") ? "OR" : "AND") + " (Status = 'Approved')";
    }

    if (Rejected.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += (sqlfilter.Contains("AND") ? "OR" : "AND") + " (Status = 'Rejected')";
    }

    dv.RowFilter = sqlfilter;

    gvconsumer.DataSource = dv;
    gvconsumer.DataBind();
```

for filter:

tring FilrterConsumer = "SELECT ConsumerBiller.id, ConsumerMaster.LastName, ConsumerMaster.FirstName, ConsumerBiller.Status, ConsumerBiller.DateCreated "
                                   + "FROM ConsumerMaster "
                                   + "JOIN ConsumerBiller on ConsumerMaster.id = ConsumerBiller.ConsumerID "
                                   + "WHERE ConsumerBiller.MerchantID = @MerchantID AND ConsumerBiller.Status <> 'DELETED' AND ConsumerBiller.Status <> 'CANCELLED'";

```
        string[] param = { "@MerchantID" };
        object[] paramVal = { MerchantID };

        return ClassDBQuery.ExecDataReader(FilrterConsumer, param, paramVal);
```

Comment: can you show at least the `HTML` ? Usually there must be something that connects the `checkbox` with the items you want to show. It can either be `class` or `data-*` or same column and so on. Then you just hide the rest and show the ones corresponding to the checkbox. This is somewhat vague since it depends on the structure.

Comment: @Spokey > i posted my code for gridview and checkbox..also the codebehind of my filter

Comment: Please post the generated one

Comment: @Spokey > generated..?the one in the filter? i added my code for that